# Handle all mongoose errors such as duplicate

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I'm wondering about how handle properly mongoose errors such as:

```
"name": "MongoError",
"err": "E11000 duplicate key error index: DB.users.$login_1  dup key: { : \"vado\" }",
"code": 11000,
"n": 0,
"connectionId": 578,
"ok": 1
```

Currently, I already have a workflow to manage errors, and not only mongoose errors.
From the controller, I call my Validator (use node-validator) to check each fields in the request (get/post), if something is wrong, it call a callback methods with a predefined error message for each error.

```
d: data, 
e: errors, 
k: key, 
m: message (key of the message), 
a: message args, 
s: status, 
t: type of error (v: validationError)
```

This is just for you to understand the "design".

```
{
  "d": {
    "e": [
      {
        "k": "email",
        "m": "__10_14"
      },
      {
        "k": "email",
        "m": {
          "m": {
            "m": "__10_11",
            "a": [
              4,
              30
            ]
          },
          "a": [
            4,
            30
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "k": "email",
        "m": "__10_13"
      }
    ]
  },
  "s": false,
  "t": "v"
}
```

So, basically, this Validator is able to manage all kind of errors, can be based on model fields using a mongoose.Schema or other validations without any link with models/db.

Now, I'm wondering about mongoose errors validation and I'm looking for a proper way to do it because my Validator is not capable to handle them. (And should not be actually, maybe another MongooseValidator inheriting Validator but I'm not sure)

I found https://github.com/leepowellcouk/mongoose-validator but it acts like my validator, but it doesn't looks like be able to handle properly raising errors from "duplicate", this kind of errors.

What I want to do is always handle in a proper way all exceptions throwed by mongoose to have a predefined message each time.

I also want to create methods to check duplicate and everything but I think that I'll use inheritance between models to do that.

Do these errors generated in production? Showing the DB and paths and everything? (I can't test)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. It's not until a `save`/`update` that these errors would be generated reliably (as it's not until those operations that a duplicate could be 100% detected/prevented). So in the callbacks, check the error?

Comment: What is the best way to check the error in the callback? Using the code? I guess so because I don't see any other way to be sure what's the error exactly is.

Comment: Unfortunately, MongoDb doesn't send back the best error structures. You'll need to do a string check if you're interested in specific errors.

Comment: That's just so bad...

Comment: Here is my own solution.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080956/how-overload-mongoose-model-instance-nodejs-typescript